# Understanding how to check subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

So here's my problem. I'm trying to do some practice on Subspace of vectors, and this was a problem in the book.

> Determine if the given set is a subspace of $P_n$, the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$, for an appropriate value of $n$. Justify your answers.
>
> 1. All polynomials of the form $p(t)=a+t^2$, where a is in $R$.
> 2. All polynomials in $P_n$ such that $p(0)=0$.

For one thing, I don't understand how to check Subspaces. I know the following for them:

> A subspace of a vector space $V$ is a subset $H$ of $V$ that has three properties: 
>       a. The zero vector of $V$ is in $H$?
>       b. $H$ is closed under vector addition. That is, for each **u** and **v** in $H$, the sum **u + v** is in $H$. 
>       c. $H$ is closed under multiplication by scalars. That is, for each ***u*** in $H$ and each scalar $c$, the vector $c$**u** is in $H$

How do I use this information to check the problem above? What's the actual math involved for this? My book only gives me this info and doesn't really explain anything about it.

Comment: In 1. is $p(t)=a+t^2$ or $p(t)=a+2t$?

Comment: The first one. I didn't catch that Sorry. I'll fix it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is not: the zero polynomial is not in the set.
2. Let us check each property:

a. The zero vector is in the set as if $p(t)=0 \Rightarrow p(0)=0$. Checked.

b. Let us denote by $p_1(t)$ and $p_2(t)$ two polynomials which satisfy $p_1(0)=0=p_2(0)$. Then $(p_1 + p_2)(0)=p_1(0)+p_2(0)=0$. Checked.

c. If $p(0)=0$, then $(cp)(0)=cp(0)=0$. Checked.

Then the set of all polynomials that satisfy $p(0)=0$ is a subspace.

Comment: What about $a$ in $a+t^2$. Don't we need to check that or are we just checking $t$?
EDIT:  I see what u did there but I still don't understand what happened to $a$. Do we set it to $0$ too or a different number?

Comment: The zero vector for vector space made up of polynomials is the zero polynomial $p(t)=0$. Even if $a$ is zero, $t^2\neq 0$.

Comment: This is probably a basic question but why is $t^2$ not equal to $0$? I want to make sure I understand this fully.

Comment: For being a zero polynomial it would need being zero for *any* $t$, not only a specific one.

Comment: Remember that the polynomials are vectors for arbitrary $t$. So if the properties do not hold for arbitrary $t$, they are not satisfied.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this problem. does it have anything to do with the Vector space rule 'there is a zero vector $0$ in $V$, such that $u+0=u$'?

Comment: Yes, it is this rule. A subspace **is** a vector space, so it must have a zero vector.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! I realize now that I need to look at those rules more!

Answer (score 0):

Quick elaboration on the criteria you have above: a *subspace* $H$ of a vector space $V$ is a subset that is itself a vector space under the vector addition and scalar multiplication of $V$.

It can be shown that the conditions you listed are necessary and sufficient for a subset $H$ to be a subspace of $V$. Thus, the properties you have above constitute a characterization of a subspace and not a definition.